# Barplot code in R working outside function but not inside

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a piece of code that works fine outside the function but not inside the function(R programming language).

I am reading an Excel file with:

```
myFile = read.csv2("myFile.csv", na.strings = c("-", "k.A"))
```

There are a number of columns in this file like gender(Geschlecht), grades, semesters etc...

I then run the following code which gives me the bar plot for the gender column.

```
barplot(prop.table(table(myFile$Geschlecht)))
```

I want to make a function that I can use to print a barplot for any column, as long as I know the name of the column heading.

This is the function I made:

```
mybarplot = function(dataCat, Title){
  barplot(prop.table(table(myFile$dataCat)))
}
```

I then call the function like this:

```
mybarplot(Geschlecht,"Geschlecht")
```

This gives me the following error and warnings:

```
*Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) :
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values*
```

As far as I can see, this has something to do with the NA values in my file? These values are specified by k.A or - in my Excel file(German language in case you are wondering).

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction so I can take care of this as i'm stuck on this since day before yesterday.

Comment: Unfortunately, R wont accept variable names for subsetting when using `$` syntax. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names

Comment: Change `myFile$dataCat` to `myFile[[dataCat]]`

Comment: @anotherfred it says object 'Geschlecht' not found. And I am not exactly sure what your first comment means but im trying to find out more about it.

Comment: When you call the function, Geshlect needs to be in quotes.

Comment: thanks. It works now. I'll now try to learn the difference between the $ operator and the [] thing using the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

To call columns using dollar sign '$' is sometimes being picky. Please try to select column by data[[column]] (like @anotherfred said) or function subset `subset(myFile, select=Geschlecht)` and don't forget to convert variables format into numeric `as.numeric()` if the column you attempt to apply has digits.